# How to install gettext extension for php on Heroku?

Tags: php, heroku, composer-php, gettext

I can't install `gettext` extension on Heroku plataform. On development enviroment `gettext` works, but not on Heroku.

My struture:

```
/app
    /web
        .user.ini
        gettext.php
        index.php
    composer.json
    composer.lock
    Procfile
    README.md
```

**.user.ini**

```
extension = gettext.so
```

**composer.json**:

```
{
   "require": {
      "php": "~5.6.4",
      "slim/slim": "~2.6",
      "nategood/httpful": "*",
      "gettext": "*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
      "heroku/heroku-buildpack-php": "*"
   }
}
```

And the code **gettext.php**:

```
if (!function_exists("gettext")){ echo "gettext is not installed\n";}
else{echo "gettext is supported\n";}
```

Return:

```
gettext is not installed
```

And when I try `heroku run bash` and after `composer update`:

```
Problem 1
   - The requested PHP extension ext-gettext * is missing from your system.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly you need to use the ext- prefix to apply extensions.

```
{
   "require": {
      "ext-gettext": "*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
      "heroku/heroku-buildpack-php": "*"
   }
}
```

Run `composer update`

If you still get error it means composer cannot update your vendor files for gettext. I had same issue and think it's a composer problem.

For true parity you should try and obtain the the lib required but you could just ignore the lack of a local gettext  with:

```
composer update --ignore-platform-reqs
```

Composer will then run without error and you can then push that up to Heroku.
Heroku will then build PHP with gettext enabled.

Comment: Thank you! Problem was `--ignore-platform-reqs` because I'm a OSX user.